# android app has stopped

Tags: android, exception

I have a problem with the Main method. I have a button called studentLife, wherever I click it, it brings a grid view with pictures. That part works fine, but when I click a particular image I want to bring the FullImage.class. When I click an image i get (GMITApp has stopped !)

```
I got a nullPointerException at line 141 which is: 
          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImage.class);
```

My code:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button studentLife = (Button) findViewById(R.id.student_life);
    //declare a grid view variable 
    GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

    studentLife.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);
            GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
            // instance of ImageAdapter class
            gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext()));

        }
    }); // end of studentLife.setOnClickListener




    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            // sending image id to FullScreenActivity
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImage.class);
            // passing array index
            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(i);       
        }
    });


}// end of onCreate
```

here is the Image Class:

```
    public class FullImage extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_image);
        //get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();
        // selected image id
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);

        //implement up navigation
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_full_image, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            //this is called when the home up button is pressed in the action bar
            Intent parentActivityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            parentActivityIntent.addFlags(
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(parentActivityIntent);
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

here is what i got when i changed `getApplicationContext()` to `MainActivity.this`

```
03-29 12:34:05.523: E/StrictMode(635): null
03-29 12:34:05.523: E/StrictMode(635): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf36d8 that was originally bound here
03-29 12:34:05.523: E/StrictMode(635):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
03-29 12:34:05.523: E/StrictMode(635):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
03-29 12:34:05.523: E/StrictMode(635):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
03-29 12:34:05.523: E/StrictMode(635):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
03-29 12:34:05.523: E/StrictMode(635):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
03-29 12:34:05.523: E/StrictMode(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
03-29 12:34:05.523: E/StrictMode(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
03-29 12:34:05.523: E/StrictMode(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
03-29 12:34:05.523: E/StrictMode(635):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
03-29 12:34:05.523: E/StrictMode(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
03-29 12:34:05.523: E/StrictMode(635):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
```

Comment: Check you android logCat. Here you can find your exception with line number.

Comment: I got a nullPointerException at line 141 which is: Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImage.class)

Comment: @WiolaStępniak : plz post full log with question to get more help from us

Comment: You can replace `getApplicationContext()` with `this` but i don't think that this solve your problem. Post log output pls.

Answer (score 1):

Replace **`getApplicationContext()`** with **`YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME.this`**.

P.S.: Please always share logCat info along with your code when asking for questions.

Comment: Of course it doesn't work because `getAppContext` only return actual context so in this case is same if you use `getapp..` or `this`.

Comment: @WELLCZECH: Your logCat suggests that you have the problem in an AsyncTask which you have been using. Are you using any?

Comment: I don't really know much about, I haven't changed anything just run the app with normal settings